# fb messenger bot: bot ask user for answers

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

Currently, I've a Python code. That process the incomming message from a Facebook messenger User. But this is a pasive chat against the chat bot. I'd like to do the following.

```
User: Pay
Bot: Please type the username of the person you want to pay.
User: eddwinpaz
Bot: Please type the amount you want to send.
User: 100.00
Bot: Are you sure you want to send 100.00 to Eddwinpaz?
```

Some how if the user in this conversation does not answers on the exact order the app wont be able to do the payment. There is a way to get the previous text and see if its answering in the correct order. Or give some logic in order to store in a session_array[sender_id,username,amount] and after I send the user a Button(Yes,No) I can actually perform the payment.

Because I need to store on the server the values regarding a question. Other example is.

```
Bot: what is your email?
User: myemail@gmail.com
Bot: your email has been saved!
```

Comment: What about input validation? For instance, a first answer has to be a valid username that exists in the payment system? The second is a valid digit, etc

Comment: but somehow I need to know the context. Because I only get the answer but Don't get the context. I can get a Yes but yes from what? :( Im trying to store this on a session but still from what question does that text comes from? html forms hold name="myfield" and value="myvalue"

Comment: If I make a question to the bot I can answer it. like whats the weather.. but not the other way around. Because bot knows the context but I do not.

Comment: I am sorry, it is very hard to understand what is the problem without an experience of FB bots creation unless there is more information about architecture. 
Could you please describe a request/response format of communication between a user, a bot and a server?

Comment: @Taras User types Pay and facebook sends this pay text message to my server, after this I parse a if condition if "pay" in message_text: then I execute a series of questions like you see above. the issue is that he could answer anything and I wont  be able to follow the proper context I need to find a way to get the previous message of "what i asked the user" so I could actualy send him the next question and validate the information properly. So far its impossible for me.

Comment: You get the user ID in every single request from Facebook

Answer (score 2):

**Facebook does not provide a way to do this, it is up to you to handle state in your code.**

This is what bot frameworks are for! Conversation management, aka state management. It comes down to either holding the past messages in a db to have state, or persisting "conversations" in memory.

There is no "right" way to do this (in my opinion) and if you want a simple answer to your question it is: **use a bot framework instead of writing this functionality from scratch.**